# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider DataServiceProvider (which is something I've never declared)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

I have this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=DataServiceProvider%20%3C-%20DataService%20%3C-%20SignupController

I am guessing it is because `DataService` is not found because it is defined in another directory? Or is it not defined correctly?

SignUpController (belongs to the main app. located in `src/public/xxx/xxx.controller.js`):

```
var app = angular.module('app');  

SignupController.$inject = ['DataService'];
function SignupController(DataService) {
    // do stuff
}

app.controller("SignupController", SignupController);
```

DataService is located in `data/dataservice.js`

```
function DataService(){
    // do stuff
}
var datamodule=angular.module('data');
datamodule.service('DataService',DataService);
```

I believe 'data' is declared properly in `data/data.module.js`

```
angular.module('data', []);
```

and has been injected to the main app in `src/public/xxx/xxx.js`

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'common','data']);
```

Reference order:

```
<script src="data/data.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="data/dataservice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/public/xxx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/public/xxx/xxx.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `DataServiceProvider` is just one way angular will try to resolve your service. is your `data` module loaded into the main app?

Comment: ```var app = angular.module('app', ['data']);```

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, among some other things `angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'common','data']);`, and the datamodule is declared as `angular.module('data', []);`

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: @lukehutton thanks. I believe I have injected data to the main app. Please see updated question

Comment: Have you included `data/dataservice.js` after `data/data.module.js` in your scripts ( I am talking about the actual files and `<script>` tags in your `html` file)?
This message only says the dependency injector could not find your `DataService` to provide it for the controller. Normally this happens when the definition file of the service is not loaded properly.

Comment: @AliMotevallian I checked. data.module and dataservice are referenced in that order, and both before the main app. since i use netbeans, i just drag them from the file explorer and drop them into the editor area

Comment: Look for any places where you may have accidentally re-declared the `data` module, ie search your `.js` files for `"angular.module('data', ["`

Comment: ... do the same for your `app` module

Comment: I advise you create a sample on Plunkr or the like and share it with us to have a better look.

Answer (score -1):

The order you import the JS matters in this case. 
Import the data/dataservice.js before any JS where you wanted to use this service or inject the service

Comment: i declared the 'data' module first. Shouldn't I reference the module first then the service?

Comment: This is not true for Angular module dependencies

Comment: @DylanChensky You are correct. Module comes first and then before using your controller JS, you should have imported your service JS that you want to inject.

In your case, if you are trying to inject your service in SignupController then you have to import the service JS file before the SignupController JS file

Comment: That is completely incorrect. See [*"The modules can be loaded in any order (or even in parallel) because modules delay execution"*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: @Phil Dont we have to load the service JS before the controller where we are going to inject the service??

Comment: @CrazyMac nope, Angular delays execution of the module until all dependencies are resolved

Comment: @Phil I have experienced a similar issue and it worked by placing the controller files in the proper order. If you think Angular takes care of the execution, then I am not sure

Comment: @CrazyMac I am 100% sure if it. You **do** need to load the files that create the modules before attempting to add anything to them but as in OP's case, the `data` module does not need to be loaded before the `app` module

Comment: Here's an example to illustrate ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/8Gdkob6m6EF3MzOuluXD?p=preview. Note the order of `.js` files in `index.html`

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your explanation.